# Flatten list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am fairly new to Prolog and attempting an exercise to flatten a list. My attempt is below, I've seen other correct implementations, but I can't figure out what is wrong with mine in particular.

```
my_flatten(List,Flattened) :- my_flatten_acc(List,Flattened,[]).

%% When first arg is an empty list, just return the rest of what was previously flattened
my_flatten_acc([],Flattened,Flattened).

%% When first arg is a list, whose first element empty list
my_flatten_acc([[]|T],Flattened,Acc) :- my_flatten_acc(T,Flattened,Acc).

%% First arg is a list, whose first element is a nonempty list
my_flatten_acc([[H|T]|T2],Flattened,[H|Acc]) :- my_flatten_acc([T|T2],Flattened,Acc).

%% First arg is a list, but not any of the above
my_flatten_acc([H|T],Flattened,[H|Acc]) :- my_flatten_acc(T,Flattened,Acc).
```

This fails on pretty much all non-empty inputs "List", and I have no idea why.

I have seen correct implementations of flatten (Both in other questions here, and in p07 [here](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Emeidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/) where I first encountered the exercise), but I'm not asking for a correct implementation, I just want to figure out what I've misunderstood in my attempt above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query `?- my_flatten([[1,2],[3,4]], Result).` and which of the my_flatten_acc helper predicates can match?

```
my_flatten_acc([[1,2],[3,4]], Flattened, []). % the helper call

my_flatten_acc([],        Flattened, Flattened). % no, first arg mismatch
my_flatten_acc([[]|T],    Flattened, Acc).       % no, first arg mismatch
my_flatten_acc([[H|T]|T2],Flattened, [H|Acc]).   % no, third arg mismatch
my_flatten_acc([H|T],     Flattened, [H|Acc]).   % no, third arg mismatch
```

You aren't saying the accumulator *starts* as an empty list; lists are immutable so you're saying it must *be* an empty list, which makes it little use as an accumulator.

Trace from https://swish.swi-prolog.org using query `trace, my_flatten([[1,2],[3,4]], F).` shows it fails very early:

[image: https://swish.swi-prolog.org trace]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I wasn't able to interpret what the "instant fail" in the trace actually meant.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to locate the error. Simply use Prolog alone to narrow down the error. So first of all figure out where your program actually finds any solution.  You said *This fails on pretty much all non-empty inputs "List"*. Let us ask Prolog directly which solutions it finds:

```
?- length(Xs,_), my_flatten(Xs,Ys).
   Xs = [], Ys = []
;  Xs = [[]], Ys = []
;  Xs = [[],[]], Ys = []
;  Xs = [[],[],[]], Ys = []
;  Xs = [[],[],[],[]], Ys = []
;  Xs = [[],[],[],[],[]], Ys = []
;  ... .
```

So for each length there is exactly one (boring) solution. But, to be fair, at least that solution is correct.

With the next query it should be obvious that at least there is one specific error:

```
?- length(Xs,_), my_flatten_acc(Xs, Cs0,Cs).
   Xs = [], Cs0 = Cs
;  Xs = [[]], Cs0 = Cs
;  Xs = [[_A]], Cs = [_A|Cs0]
;  Xs = [[_A,_B]], Cs = [_A,_B|Cs0]
;  Xs = [[_A,_B,_C]], Cs = [_A,_B,_C|Cs0]
;  Xs = [[_A,_B,_C,_D]], Cs = [_A,_B,_C,_D|Cs0]
;  Xs = [[_A,_B,_C,_D,_E]], Cs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E|Cs0]
;  Xs = [[_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F]], Cs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F|Cs0]
;  ... .
```

By exchanging the 2nd and 3rd argument of the goal in the first rule, we can fix that. But there are still problems. In particular, there is not one unique flattened list.  Think of:

```
?- length(Xs,_), my_flatten(Xs,Ys),my_flatten(Xs,Ysi),dif(Ys,Ysi).
   Xs = [[]], Ys = [], Ysi = [[]]
;  Xs = [[_A]], Ys = [_A], Ysi = [_A,[]]
;  ... .
```

At first you might be tempted to prefer a d-bugger over formulating your own queries, but at least when working with constraints you will see that this method is often more robust.